# Cómo implementar un salto de línea automático en un JEditorPane con setEditorKit

Tags: java, java-swing

Tengo un problema con un objeto del tipo `JEditorPane`.

Cuando declaro un objeto `JEditorPane` y ejecuto el programa principal, si lo que escribo es más largo que el tamaño del `JEditorPane`, se hace un salto de línea automáticamente.

El problema está cuando al objeto le digo

```
setEditorKit(new StyledEditorKit());
```

no hace el salto de línea, sigue escribiendo de largo.

Por ejemplo:

Si lo hago de esta manera, funciona el salto de línea:

```
JEditorPane jep = new JEditorPane();
```

Pero si lo hago de esta manera, no hace el salto de línea, escribe de largo:

```
JEditorPane jep = new JEditorPane ();
jep.setEditorKit (new StyledEditorKit());
```

O sea, al declarar

```
jep.setEditorKit (new StyledEditorKit());
```

el salto de línea automático no funciona.

¿Cuál podría ser el problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

en tu caso, si que sigue haciendo el salto de línea pero solo lo aplica a palabras.
Por ejmplo; si escribes desde el principio una palabra tan larga que ocupa todo el ancho, no va a hacer salto de línea; pero en el momento en el que escribas un nueva palabra a continuación, con un espacio antes de la anterior, si que lo hará.

Ante esta limitación, yo lo que uso para estos casos, es un `JTextArea` (que cumple más o menos la misma función) con un `LineWrap`

Primero le dirás al objeto que quieres que salte de line con: `setLineWrap(true);` 
y después especificarás cómo quieres que salte de linea con: `setWrapStyleWord(true);` por ejemplo.

El código de un JTextArea sería por ejemplo;

```
    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    textArea.setBounds(x, y, ancho, alto);
    textArea.setLineWrap(true);
    textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    add(textArea);
```

Espero que te haya ayudado! :)